# Best index selection for storing Country Code + Phone

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 choices to store 2 fields: country code + phone

a) country code  (can be 1, 2 or 3 characters)

b) phone (can be 8-12 digits)

These 2 fields will be used to create a 2-field index:

1. varchar(3) and varchar(12)
2. char(3) and char(12) -- but waste of space for char(12)?
3. smallint and varchar(12)
4. smallint and char(12)  -- but waste of space for char(12)?

Which one should I choose for index efficiency?
would a SmallInt + varchar slow index down, or string fields should pair with string fields?

Grateful for any advice anyone can offer.

Comment: Is country code numeric?

Comment: yes, it is. something like 7, 25, 105... not SP, US, KR etc

Answer (score 1):

You have described two non-number fields that can have up to 3 and 12 characters each.  The first choice seems like the obvious choice.

I say these are non-number fields because arithmetic and (generally) comparison logic on the values would not follow numeric rules.  It doesn't make sense to add 1 to either value.

In addition, it is quite possible that leading zeros are important.

If you are using ISO 3-character country codes, then you know the values are 3 characters, and you can use `CHAR(3)` instead of `VARCHAR(3)`.  Of course, a smallint would also be appropriate.

Comment: One question : sometimes the country code is 7, or 25 or 325.  so I'm just wondering char(3) would be more wasteful than varchar(3)... but at the same time, will the the index perform more efficiently using  char(3) + varchar(12) than varchar(3)+varchar(12), since the first part of index is char(3) is fixed length? I seem to think it should be so - can anyone confirm?

Comment: @PeterW. . . . I think you are overthinking the optimization.  Fixed length keys in indexes are slightly more efficient but the difference pails compared to having or not having an index.  Unless you have specific reasons to be highly concerned about performance or data space, then any of the options is fine from an indexing perspective.

Comment: Does MySQL handle a 2byte first field better than a 3-byte char in the index for reading and writing index? (sorry, but I hope to utilise the best method for indexing)... as I'm worried if the records grow to a few million or more, the speed difference and performance bottleneck may become significant.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the difference in performance or size on a few million rows.  If you had tens of billions of rows, then such considerations might be important.